# electron-builder is not calling x64 installer [win10]

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

electron-builder is calling 32bit installer causing paths point to WOW64 equivalents instead of the real x64 paths.

Process that calls installer is 64bit, then 32bit installer is called and eventually application that is "runAfterFinish" is 64bit.

[image: Procesess]

How can I overcome this issue and force installer to call x64 version?

Tested on Windows 10, electron-builder 19.16.3

Builder ran with --x64 option gives output:

`Building NSIS installer
  Packaging NSIS installer for arch x64`

Calling installer with ... /D=path argument would also solve the problem, but it is not taking this into account.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: @Anders When I want to use C:\Windows\System32\... it points to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\... instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about electron builder but I do know that a 32-bit NSIS installer can install 64-bit programs.

Use `SetRegView` to change to the 64-bit registry view and use the macros in x64.nsh to turn filesystem redirection on and off.

Comment: `SetRegView` is already used [here in the script](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/f24c3895ace9585fc591ed1686a44e41841b0f53/packages/electron-builder/templates/nsis/common.nsh#L24), that's why I expect NSIS to point to correct path.

Comment: Set**Reg**View only affects the registry.